# Script to Copy multiple sheets from an Excel file and convert it to a Google Sheets file

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have an Excel file with 3 tabs (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3) attached to a Gmail message and I would like these to copy to a Google Sheet file with 3 tabs (SheetA, SheetB, SheetC).  The problem I am facing is that my script dumps the data from Excel Sheet 1 and repeats it on all 3 of my Google Sheet tabs.  How do I adjust my script so I can copy data from all 3 tabs over?

```
function MyFunction() {
 
 var selectedSheets = ["SheetA","SheetB","SheetC"]; // select the sheets you want to run the function for
 var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets(); // get all sheets

  var sheet1= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetA");
  
  sheet1.clearContents();
  sheet1.clearFormats();

 var sheet2= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetB");
  sheet2.clearContents();
  sheet2.clearFormats();

var sheet3= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetC");
  sheet3.clearContents();
  sheet3.clearFormats();

  var thread = GmailApp.search('from:linked.tracker@gmail.com subject:"Email Subject Test"', 0, 1)[0];
  
  var attachment = thread.getMessages()[thread.getMessageCount() - 1].getAttachments();
  var xlsxBlob = attachment[0]; //gets the attachment blob
  var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id; //uploads the attachment to gdrive
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];  //opens the file in the background to access data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //gets the data and stores it under 'data'
  sheet1.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); //like in the CSV function too uploads the data to our gsheet

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];  //opens the file in the background to access data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //gets the data and stores it under 'data'
  sheet2.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); //like in the CSV function too uploads the data to our gsheet

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];  //opens the file in the background to access data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //gets the data and stores it under 'data'
  sheet3.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); //like in the CSV function too uploads the data to our gsheet

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Some of the best resources for learning Google Apps Script include the [Fundamentals of Apps Script with Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/apps-script-fundamentals-1) codelab, the [Extending Google Sheets page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets), [javascript.info](https://javascript.info/), [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the script is repeating the following code line 3 times:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];
```

More specifically, the problem is that `[0]` is the same for the three lines. To quickly fix this, use `[0]`, `[1]` and `[2]` respectively.

Below is the original script with the suggested changes applied:

```
function MyFunction() {
 
 var selectedSheets = ["SheetA","SheetB","SheetC"]; // select the sheets you want to run the function for
 var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets(); // get all sheets

  var sheet1= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetA");
  
  sheet1.clearContents();
  sheet1.clearFormats();

 var sheet2= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetB");
  sheet2.clearContents();
  sheet2.clearFormats();

var sheet3= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetC");
  sheet3.clearContents();
  sheet3.clearFormats();

  var thread = GmailApp.search('from:linked.tracker@gmail.com subject:"Email Subject Test"', 0, 1)[0];
  
  var attachment = thread.getMessages()[thread.getMessageCount() - 1].getAttachments();
  var xlsxBlob = attachment[0]; //gets the attachment blob
  var convertedSpreadsheetId = Drive.Files.insert({mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS}, xlsxBlob).id; //uploads the attachment to gdrive
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[0];  //opens the file in the background to access data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //gets the data and stores it under 'data'
  sheet1.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); //like in the CSV function too uploads the data to our gsheet

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[1];  //opens the file in the background to access data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //gets the data and stores it under 'data'
  sheet2.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); //like in the CSV function too uploads the data to our gsheet

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(convertedSpreadsheetId).getSheets()[2];  //opens the file in the background to access data
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); //gets the data and stores it under 'data'
  sheet3.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); //like in the CSV function too uploads the data to our gsheet

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ruben !!  It worked :)